# automatically increase page size in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

i want to increase page size to print the billing information using billing machine that does not break the page until output ends. i am using this code but it will break the page after 80 by 80 size, i want to fix page width to 80 but want automated height.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(80,80));
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);    
$mpdf->Output();
```

How page size automatically increase without page break ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in table element by adding this

```
<table style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
```